# Ruby: How do I define a datetime field in YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, yaml

I'm creating test data for a Rails app.  How do I define the value for a datetime field in YAML?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

when rails generates fixture files it uses the following format in the yaml files

```
one:
 something_at: 2010-02-11 11:02:57
 something_on: 2010-02-11
```

Answer (score 10):

Found the answer [here](http://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html):

```
model:
   datetime_field: 2010-04-16 16:32:03 -5
```

Answer (score 4):

When I yaml DateTime, I generally pack it as a string:

```
foo = DateTime.now
foo_yaml = YAML.dump(foo.to_s)
foo = DateTime.parse(YAML.load(foo_yaml))
puts foo
```

I'd be interested to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4):

For me works it wrapped in " "

```
created_at: "2010-02-11 11:02:57"
```

Answer (score 2):

With Time zone: 
`created_at: 2013-09-25 16:00:00 +0800`